# How to import a file from another folder in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tsx file in below path

app/frontend/src/pages/main/_form/output.tsx

now i want to import this file "output.tsx" into "Parent.tsx" file which is in below path

app/frontend/src/pages/Lists/_form/formSteps/Step1/Parent.tsx

how can i import output.tsx file in Parent.tsx file

i have tried below

import {something] from '../../output.tsx';

but the path seems to be errorneous. could someone help me out with this. thanks

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common root is `pages` which is 4 levels up from `Parent.tsx`, so below should work fine

`../../../../main/_form/output.tsx`

Also if its a default import use like this

`import Output from '../../../../main/_form/output.tsx`;